# Shuffling the position of shape randomly

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
If AnswerOrder(0) = 1 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Top = 218
ElseIf AnswerOrder(0) = 2 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Top = 290
ElseIf AnswerOrder(0) = 3 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Top = 361
ElseIf AnswerOrder(0) = 4 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a1").Top = 432
End If

If AnswerOrder(1) = 1 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Top = 218
ElseIf AnswerOrder(1) = 2 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Top = 290
ElseIf AnswerOrder(1) = 3 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Top = 361
ElseIf AnswerOrder(1) = 4 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a2").Top = 432
End If

If AnswerOrder(2) = 1 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Top = 218
ElseIf AnswerOrder(2) = 2 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Top = 290
ElseIf AnswerOrder(2) = 3 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Top = 361
ElseIf AnswerOrder(2) = 4 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a3").Top = 432
End If

If AnswerOrder(3) = 1 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Top = 218
ElseIf AnswerOrder(3) = 2 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Top = 290
ElseIf AnswerOrder(3) = 3 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Top = 361
ElseIf AnswerOrder(3) = 4 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Left = 303
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a4").Top = 432
End If
```

There has to be a better way to execute this macro instead of writing so many lines. Any suggestions?

Context: I am trying to randomly shuffle the order of four shapes which is in Slide 3. I make an array called `AnswerOrder` which contains `1,2,3,4`. I shuffle the array and then execute the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't have a PowerPoint at hand, but I wrote some sample code in Excel, hopefully this would help shorten the code a little bit and make it more maintainable.

The idea is to extract the code that sets the position of a shape to a separate subroutine, and in the main sub, iterate over the AnswerOrder and call that subroutine on specified shapes.

```
Public Sub set_shapePosition(determinant As Long, shp As Shape)
    ' can also put shp.Left = 303 here
    Select Case determinant
        Case 1
            shp.Left = 303
            shp.Top = 218
        Case 2
            shp.Left = 303
            shp.Top = 290
        Case 3
            shp.Left = 303
            shp.Top = 361
        Case 4
            shp.Left = 303
            shp.Top = 432
    End Select
    ' Also shape Top is around 71 pixels different to one and another,
    ' We can write below code for simpler implementation
    ' Getting rid of select case statement:
    ' shp.Top = 218 + 71 * (determinant - 1)
End Sub

Public Sub main()
    ' Define slide here.....
    Set slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)

    ' ...Define and shuffle AnswerOrder here.......
    '
    ' .............................................

    For i = LBound(AnswerOrder) To UBound(AnswerOrder)
        Call set_shapePosition(AnswerOrder(i), slide.Shapes("a" & i+1) )
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For j = 0 To 3

If AnswerOrder(j) = 1 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Top = 218
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Left = 303
ElseIf AnswerOrder(j) = 2 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Top = 288
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Left = 303
ElseIf AnswerOrder(j) = 3 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Top = 363
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Left = 303
ElseIf AnswerOrder(j) = 4 Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Top = 432
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("a" & j + 1).Left = 303
End If

Next j
```

This makes the code more neat.